# Rmarkdown table that works with output_format='all'

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I want to knit an Rmarkdown document that contains a table to .pdf, .md and .html simultaneously and I want the table to be appropriately formatted for each of the three output formats.

I use the following code:

````
---    
title: "Title"
author: "Author Name"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B %Y')`"
output:
    github_document: default
    md_document: default
    pdf_document: default
---

```{r eval=FALSE, include=FALSE}
# Note: The next line creates README.pdf, README.md and README.html at once. 
rmarkdown::render('README.Rmd', output_format = 'all')
```

```{r}
# Table
knitr::kable(head(mtcars))
```
````

Note that I use `rmarkdown::render('README.Rmd', output_format = 'all')` to knit to the three output formats.

I have tried knitr::kable(), pander::pander(), xtable::xtable() and a few other ways, but every time the table does not get formatted properly in one or two of the output formats. How can I do this?

Comment: What is a not-properly formatted table? Can you use only one output style?

Comment: If you copy paste the above code into an empty Rmarkdown file and run the codeblock with `rmarkdown:render()` you can check the generated .html, .pdf and .md files and you will see that the table is only rendered correctly in the .html file. No, I do not want just one output style, I want all output styles (that's the point of output_format='all').

Comment: For me it works fine. You have to use `rmarkdown::render('README.Rmd', output_format = 'all')` outside the RMD file.